# Android deep link "wc:" scheme

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am trying to recognize the following as a deep link in android

```
wc:1a15e8b5-8470-47fa-985f-cf11b4c89067@1?bridge=https%3A%2F%2Fbridge.walletconnect.org&key=f92fb2ed74d628a6a286e416e4df2fbfa88d58e6826007c021b9f5920567cdd5
```

I have set up my AndroidManifest to be as follows:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|layoutDirection|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="wc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However when I try to scan the relevant qr with the camera app, nothing happens.
What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you just need this // after wc:?

Comment: i cannot do anything to change the link, the link is provided by an external app, which i have nothing to do with. I think i need more settings in my manifest, but i dont know what they are

Comment: Can you try to add this - android:host = "*Fbridge.walletconnect.org"

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, i have tried it, unfortunately it doesnt work, i get net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Actually I think you can't use provided text as deep-link, hope i'm wrong

Comment: You can also try mimeType attribute instead of scheme. Take a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#mime

Comment: adding mimeType alone makes the app not compile, it forces to add scheme, adding scheme in that case makes the app not installable

Comment: What are you doing with this code? Specifically, what does the wc: at the beginning tell the link to do? I stumbled across a similar example but it was a bit of malicious code someone was trying to get me to use.

Comment: this is wallet connect scheme